# Why does the compiler complain about my dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to figure out the reason for the compile error in my code:

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual ~A(){}
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
    virtual ~B(){}
};

class D: public B
{
    public:
    virtual ~D(){}
};

template <class X, class Y>
X* fun(X* p){return dynamic_cast<Y*>(p);}

int main()
{
    A* q = dynamic_cast<B*>(new D());
    A* p = fun<D,B>(new D());
}
```

To me it seems like the pointers q and p should be pointing to the same type but for p I'm getting a compiler error saying "invalid conversion from ‘B*’ to ‘D*’". The only time I don't get an error is when I change the classes in a way that B is a subclass of D (thus p is a null pointer). Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

Comment: Notice you return a `X*` and not `Y*`.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the problem, so the last line of code will be returning a D*, but since D is a subclass of A that should be OK, right?

Comment: The problem is that `fun` can't convert from `B*` to `D*` implicitly. The `dynamic_cast` returns a `B*` but you try to then return it from a function that expects a `D*`. It looks like you meant for `fun` to return `Y*`.

Comment: You are casting the pointer to a **base** class and then trying to return that as a **derived** class pointer.

Comment: I got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <class X, class Y>
X* fun(X* p){return dynamic_cast<Y*>(p);}
```

this function takes an `X*` and returns an `X*`.

In the body, you cast it to a `Y*`.  You then attempt to implicitly convert it to an `X*`.

The error you are getting is in the body of `fun`, where you take a `D*`, cast it to a `B*`, then try to implicitly cast it to a `D*` again.  That fails.  Hence your error.

When looking at compiler errors, it helps to

1. Have each statement be on its own line.  If the statement is complex, break it down into multiple statements.
2. Look at the line the compiler says the error is on.

A fix is:

```
template <class X, class Y>
Y* fun(X* p){return dynamic_cast<Y*>(p);}
```

now your code will work.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get the problem, so the last line of code will be returning a D*, but since D is a subclass of A that should be OK, right?

No, it is not OK. `D` begin a subclass of  `A` is irrelevant.

> Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

A pointer to a base (`B*` i.e. `Y*`) is not implicitly convertible to a pointer to derived (`D*` i.e. `X*`).

On the other hand, `A* p = fun<B,D>(new D());` would be well formed. Note the different order of template arguments. Yet on another hand, `fun` isn't very useful function.

Comment: I didn't really write that code (my professor did) so I'm not supposed to change the order of template arguments. But I now understand the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @Diba well, the program is ill-formed. If you don't change *something* about, then there is nothing to be solved.

Comment: You're right, actually what I could change was the hierarchy of the classes. I had found the solution (B being a subclass of D) but was just wondering why it doesn't work the other way round.